# Lodash Group array of object and return array of key instead of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array of objects like this

```
const data = [{name:"abc",age:"18"},{name:"dfd",age:"18"},{name:"dnss",age:"20"},{name:"dnnns",age:"12"}]
```

Using `_.groupBy(data,"age")` will return `name` as a key with array of object.

How do I return only array of `name`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`_.flow()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flow) to create a function that groups by `age`, then map the groups with [`_.mapValues()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#mapValues), and use [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#map) to pluck the names from the arrays:

```js
const { flow, groupBy, mapValues, map } = _

const fn = flow(
  arr => groupBy(arr, 'age'),
  groups => mapValues(groups, g => map(g, 'name'))  
)

const data = [{name:"abc",age:"18"},{name:"dfd",age:"18"},{name:"dnss",age:"20"},{name:"dnnns",age:"12"}]

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

And the terser [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) version:

```js
const { flow, groupBy, mapValues, map } = _

const fn = flow(
  groupBy('age'),
  mapValues(map('name'))
)

const data = [{name:"abc",age:"18"},{name:"dfd",age:"18"},{name:"dnss",age:"20"},{name:"dnnns",age:"12"}]

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for help , i need a key to be age and a value to be array of only names instead of object , i have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

> Thanks for help , i need a key to be age and a value to be array of
>   only names instead of object , i have edited my question

In this case you can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const data = [{name:"abc",age:"18"},{name:"dfd",age:"18"},{name:"dnss",age:"20"},{name:"dnnns",age:"12"},{name:'abc', age:'23'}]


const op = data.reduce((out,{name,age})=>{
  if(out[age]){
    out[age].push(name)
  } else {
    out[age] = [name]
  }
  return out
},{})

console.log(op)
```

Simply you can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const data = [{name:"abc",age:"18"},{name:"dfd",age:"18"},{name:"dnss",age:"20"},{name:"dnnns",age:"12"}]

const op = data.map(({name}) => name)

console.log(op)
```

As @ori asking for unique names you can use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) if you want unique one only

```js
const data = [{name:"abc",age:"18"},{name:"dfd",age:"18"},{name:"dnss",age:"20"},{name:"dnnns",age:"12"},{name:'abc', age:'23'}]

const op = [...new Set(data.map(({name}) => name))]

console.log(op)
```

Comment: I would add the Set solution to the answer. I think that removing duplicates is the reason he groups in the 1st place.

Comment: @OriDrori not sure. op didn't mentioned anything about it.anyways added set part too

Comment: Thanks for help , i need a key to be age and a value to be array of only names instead of object , i have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Use Array#reduce

```js
const data = [{name:"abc",age:"18"},{name:"dfd",age:"18"},{name:"dnss",age:"20"},{name:"dnnns",age:"12"}]

const res = data.reduce((a,{name,age})=>{
  if(!a[age]) a[age] = [];
  a[age].push(name);
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

after grouping you need to iterate every group and return only name:

```
const res = _.chain(data)
    .groupBy('age')
    .mapValues(group => _.map(group, 'name'))
    // or with FP .mapValues(_.partial(_.map, _, 'name'))
    .value();
```